# Manipulate existing type to make all properties optional

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a base type that looks like this:

```
type MyForm = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

Is there a way to manipulate MyForm into:

```
type MyFormOptional = {
  email?: string | null;
  password?: string | null;
}
```

by only using MyForm and transforming it?

Comment: See: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713349/make-all-properties-within-a-typescript-interface-optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713349/make-all-properties-within-a-typescript-interface-optional) which describes the mapped type, or [Extend all properties of Interface or Type to be potentially null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923328/extend-all-properties-of-interface-or-type-to-be-potentially-null) which shows adding `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which makes each property optional via the `?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) and which adds `null` to each property type:

```
type PartialAndNullable<T> =
  { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] | null }

type MyFormOptional = PartialAndNullable<MyForm>
/* type MyFormOptional = {
    email?: string | null;
    password?: string | null;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiB7ATgWygXigbwFBSglQEMBLAGwC4oBnYZUgOwHMBufKMYmmgdxQAm1OgxbsAvrlyhIUAArFkwUsXIBBRgIByAV3LliAI3IQAPABUAfJg7YoAbQDSUJlADWEEIgBmUcwF0AfmpzJ38oAB8oRj1yKElpcGg4JDQAeTBlREZVTHlFZVUNbVijE1MUlFRLXAB6ACooGWSEKoysnLisPAICIjJyYNp6JmZI6Nj2Xs5uPkEhkVHxmP0JKHraoA)